Looking for some tips on fixing a railing
Looking for some tips to fix this railing. It's pulled up from the concrete here
I'm thinking about cutting those pins or screws then either pulling them up with some pliers or using a hammer drill to loosen the concrete around then if I need to. Then patching with concrete and drop some new anchors in there.
I'll need to remove the whole railing but I'm not sure how to get underneath the other flange since it's flush with the concrete.
Also on a slightly unrelated note does anyone know what this stripping is for and what its called? It's a little hard to see but looks like a thin strip of metal with a 90 degree bend. I need to replace it.
Thanks all!

There may be enough flex in the railing to just pull it out (at least the front one).  Can you rotate that square thing that looks like it might be the head of a pin?

Ya I wasn't sure if they were pins or screws. Will be back out there next week and I'll see. Maybe I'll get lucky and they're just pins

Hmmm... can you unscrew the flanges from the rest of the railing? I see some screws the side of the flange. Otherwise, the hammerdrill seems to be your best solution.

Thanks sounds like I'm on the right track then. Guess I just feel better having someone confirm what I'm thinking before doing it
